# Submit multiple form in one click

Tags: javascript, woocommerce

So basically I'm having two forms like this:

```
<form method="post" action="url1">
    <input type="hidden" name="add-to-cart" value="product_id1">
    <input type="hidden" name="wc_bookings_field_start_date_year" value="2018">
    <input type="hidden" name="wc_bookings_field_start_date_month" value="06">
    <input type="hidden" name="wc_bookings_field_start_date_day" value="30">
    <button type="submit">Add to cart</button>
</form>

<form method="post" action="url1">
    <input type="hidden" name="add-to-cart" value="product_id2">
    <input type="hidden" name="wc_bookings_field_start_date_year" value="2018">
    <input type="hidden" name="wc_bookings_field_start_date_month" value="06">
    <input type="hidden" name="wc_bookings_field_start_date_day" value="30">
    <button type="submit">Add to cart</button>
</form>
```

Is there anyway I can merge the two button into one button that submit both forms? Kind of add both product to cart at the same time

Comment: Why have two forms if you want to submit everything?

Comment: because the value(item id) is different

Comment: why not use array of items?

Comment: Maybe the endpoint he is accessing does not have that ability.   @Work I think you need to use javascript, create an event listener on click for the button.  Then in the called function, just submit both forms.

Comment: Basically you want a simple hack to send all your forms with one button click and hide all others ? What have you tried so far ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a seperate button independent of either forms. On that Button's click event, you can submit both the forms using their submit method.

```js
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");
var forms = document.getElementsByTagName("form");
for(var i = 0; i < forms.length; i++) {
    forms[i].submit();
}
```

```html
<form method="post" action="url1">
    <input type="hidden" name="add-to-cart" value="product_id1">
    <input type="hidden" name="wc_bookings_field_start_date_year" value="2018">
    <input type="hidden" name="wc_bookings_field_start_date_month" value="06">
    <input type="hidden" name="wc_bookings_field_start_date_day" value="30">
    <button type="submit">Add to cart</button>
</form>

<form method="post" action="url1">
    <input type="hidden" name="add-to-cart" value="product_id2">
    <input type="hidden" name="wc_bookings_field_start_date_year" value="2018">
    <input type="hidden" name="wc_bookings_field_start_date_month" value="06">
    <input type="hidden" name="wc_bookings_field_start_date_day" value="30">
    <button type="submit">Add to cart</button>
</form>

<button id="myBtn">Add both</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can't do it since it will make the browser redirect to the URL specified in `action` attribute of your forms. And it can't redirect to two different locations.

To accomplish multiple form submission , you can use an `XMLHttpRequest` with  JavaScript's  [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) API or encode it in `JSON` before sending it to server.